# How to remove the four last char of all filenames in a folder c#

Tags: c#, file

I have a folder with a lot of images, all have the same name format:

```
some-random-name-min.jpg
another-random-name-min.jpg
and-another-random-name-min.jpg
```

I want to strip the last -min
Here I did a script to change the name of all the files but I only want to remove the four last char.

```
private void Rename(string fPath, string fNewName)
{
    string fExt;
    string fFromName;
    string fToName;
    int i = 1;

    //copy all files from fPath to files array
    FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(fPath).GetFiles();
    //loop through all files
    foreach (var f in files)
    {
        //get the filename without the extension
        fFromName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name);
        //get the file extension
        fExt = Path.GetExtension(f.Name);

        //set fFromName to the path + name of the existing file
        fFromName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", fPath, f.Name);
        //set the fToName as path + new name + _i + file extension
        fToName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}_{2}{3}", fPath, fNewName, i.ToString(), fExt);

        //rename the file by moving to the same place and renaming
        File.Move(fFromName, fToName);
        //increment i
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so which bit of "removing the last three characters" is causing you a problem? Are you aware of `string.Substring` and `string.Length`? (I'd strongly advise against this `f` prefix on your variable names, btw...)

Comment: String Replace is not an option?

Comment: Have you not considered using Path.GetExtension ? or Path.ChangeExtension ?

Comment: _-min_ are 4 chars.

Comment: In my foreach I put the replace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private string Remove4LastCharacter(string fName)
{
    string nameWithoutExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fName);
    // Length is less than or equal 4 => I can not remove them
    if (nameWithoutExt.Length <= 4)
    {
        return fName;
    }

    // Other cases
    string newNameWithoutExt = nameWithoutExt.Substring(0, nameWithoutExt.Length - 4);
    return newNameWithoutExt + Path.GetExtension(fName);
}
```

Apply to your code:

```
// Use Path.Combine instead
fFromName = Path.Combine(fPath, f.Name);
fNewName = Remove4LastCharacter(f.Name);
fToName = string.Format("{0}_{1}{2}", Path.Combine(fPath, fNewName), i.ToString(), fExt);
```

Comment: It's [susbstring(startIndex, length)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) - so, I would say it has to be `nameWithoutExt.Substring(0, nameWithoutExt.Length - 4);`